# Alternatives to JMeter for POST requests with different parameters (must work without GUI)

Tags: post, jmeter, load, benchmarking, apachebench

As far as I know, JMeter allows you to send multiple POST request with different parameters (e.g. `{ "value": "value1"}, {"value": "value2"}`, ...) However, I'm more comfortable using a terminal-based interface similar to ab or siege. Basically, I need to load test a server simulating the case in which some requests are not previously cached.

Are there alternatives to JMeter for Linux that are able to use different parameters for a POST request?

**UPDATE**

As far as I can tell, JMeter requires the creation of a test plan (jmx file) in order to run via the command line. Unfortunately, this test plan needs to be built using the GUI, which is precisely what I want to avoid.

**UPDATE 2**

I will use JMeter because it offers dynamic parameters for POST requests and most alternatives depend on JMeter. However, if anyone knows of a standalone library that works exclusively from the terminal (similar to ab), please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use JMeter in terminal mode, it's called Non GUI mode.

To variabilize just use CsV dataset to load variables (varName for example )per thread, then use ${varName}

See :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Nice report at end:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

If you don't want to use GUI even for building the test, then look at :

- https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter

It allows you to generate the JMX from a DSL file.

Examples here:

- https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter/tree/master/examples

DSL here:

- https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter/blob/master/lib/ruby-jmeter/DSL.md

> ```
> $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
>   require 'ruby-jmeter'
>   test do
>     csv_data_set_config name:'MyCsv', filename: '/path to file', variableNames: 'myParam'
>     threads count: 10 do
>       visit name: 'Qwant Search', url: 'https://lite.qwant.com/?q=flood.io&t=web&p=${myParam}'
>     end
>   end.jmx(file: "path to your output plan")
> ```

Save file to **ruby-jmeter-csv.rb**
You can then generate the plan with:

> ruby ruby-jmeter-csv.rb

And run it in non gui mode.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm going to do, but I can't figure out what command line arguments need to use to feed the csv dataset and to set a given variable ${varName}. Do you have an example that shows how to use it?

Comment: follow any tutorial showing how to use it in gui mode, it will run ok in non gui mode. Just ensure path to cdv file is ok

Comment: This doesn't happen at command line. CSV DataSet will fill the variable (it's one of the fields) from the CSV file (another field) at each iteration of the Thread Group. Gui or NOn Gui it works the same

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to run the task without a jmx file previously generated by the GUI.

Comment: from gui, click on the green triangle to run the plan and see if it works, that's it. Use a View Results Tree to see if you send and get what you want , put it as a child of Test Plan element

Comment: Yes. but I precisely asked for a way that didn't involve the GUI. That's why I started requesting alternatives. I updated my question previously to state that limitation.

Comment: You mean you don't want to use GUI even for building the test ? In that case I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's exactly right. Based on your answer, should I assume that the only way to send dynamic parameters in a POST request is to use JMeter (with or without a wrapper to run it without GUI)? I was expecting a more straightforward  way to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working ruby-jmeter sample. But, Clearly if you cannot  use gui at all, (I don't know why because you should be able to even on linux) you're loosing an important feature of JMeter, as it's an IDE for test creation.

Comment: It is not so much that I can't use a GUI, but there are a bunch of minor reasons why I'd rather not to use it (e.g. old laptop behaves better without GUIs, generations of reports and manipulation is faster without GUIs, GUIs are kind of ugly, etc) However, if there are no other alternatives that work without GUI "out of the box", I guess I will use JMeter.

Comment: you need gui only for test building. Report generation can be done on demand or at end of test in non gui mode. For alternatives, see Dmitri answer although I think jmeter is still the best choice as of today :) Then accept the answer you find the best

Comment: Yes, JMeter is needed for many of those tools, so I think I will stick to JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

In fact JMeter GUI should be used for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to running the load test - it is recommended to run JMeter in [command line mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), via [Ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) or [Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin). Also there is a couple of more "geek" alternatives, i.e.:

- JMeter .jmx scripts are basically XML files so you can use your favourite text editor to create or amend them
- You can use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) to create and kick off JMeter tests using Java language

---

If you're still looking for an alternative, here are few free and open source load testing tools

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) - you can write scripts in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) - you can write scripts in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)-based DSL
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) - this guy exists for Linux and Unix-based platforms only, Erlang-based. Scripts are XML files.
- [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) - automation framework which supports all aforementioned tools (and some more), Python based, configuration files have simple [YAML](http://yaml.org/) syntax.

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) for more information on the above tools and comparison of them with JMeter

Comment: Thank you. I like Taurus, but I think it is using JMeter as a backend. If that is the case, I prefer to use JMeter, but I'm still not sure how to use a csv file for dynamic parameters in a POST request. Most tutorials show how to do it using the GUI.